# Dog starts running away from owner. After 10 meters, owner starts running after dog.

Tags: calculus

> A man is walking his dog when suddenly the dog runs away. After
>   running 10 meters, the owner startes running after the dog. The
>   distance between the dog and the owner is given  in meters for t
>   seconds by  $$d(t)=\frac{90t}{t^2+14}, t\in[0,30]$$
>
> Consider $t=0$ the instant in which the dog started running and that
>   the dog was always ahead of the owner.
>
> The owner runs at a constant velocity, running 4 meters every second.
>   Show that $$\frac{90t+180}{t^2+4t+18}+4t$$ is the distance, in meters,
>   ran by the dog t seconds after the owner started running.
>
> Using a calculator, determine the velocity of the dog 5 seconds after
>   the owner started running after him.

I know that $\frac{90t+180}{t^2+4t+18}$ is $\frac{90t}{t^2+14}$ with $t$ replaced with $t+2$ (2 because 10 = d(2)), and I also know that the function that gives the total distance ran by the owner is $4t$.

This should be enough to answer the "Show that" part, however, I don't understand some things:

1. Why is it $\frac{90t+180}{t^2+4t+18}+4t$ and not $\frac{90t+180}{t^2+4t+18}-4t$? In fact, why is the distance ran by the owner even included in this formula? Isn't it supposed to only about the dog?
2. How would you translate this formula to plain english?

As for the second part, I tried calculating this using t=5, and I got $\approx 3.2$

But my book says the solution is $3.2$ms$^{-1}$. What does ms$^{-1}$ mean? Did I solve it correctly?

Comment: Metres per second. $ms^{-1}=\frac{m}{s}$

Comment: @samjoe Then what is the difference between ms and ms$^{-1}$?

Comment: The dimension of speed is $\frac{\text{length}}{\text{time}}$, right?

Comment: @MarkRead ms = meters $\cdot$ seconds = length $\cdot$ time. Not a unit of velocity.

Comment: @samjoe Yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In fact, why is the distance ran by the owner even included in this formula? Isn't it supposed to only about the dog?"

- Remember that this formula represents the distance between the dog and owner. So the formula is about both the owner and the dog.

Let $D(t)$ be the distance that the dog runs, and $O(t)$ be the distance that the owner runs, both dependent on time the owner started running. You were able to find that:
$$D(t) - O(t) = \frac{90t + 180}{t^2 + 4t + 18}$$
We also know that $O'(t) = 4$. Therefore $O(t) = 4t + C$. But since $O(0) = 0$, $C = 0$. So:
$$D(t) - 4t = \frac{90t + 180}{t^2 + 4t + 18}$$
$$D(t) = \frac{90t + 180}{t^2 + 4t + 18} + 4t$$

"How would you translate this formula to plain english?"

- What is plain english? What are you missing about the formula?